# Extracting data using regex from bank feed

Tags: regex

I am looking to extract some text from a raw credit card feed for a workflow. I have gotten almost where I want to but am struggling with the final piece of information I'm trying to extract.

An example of the raw feed is:

```
LEO'SFINEFOOD&WINEHARTWELLJune350.0735.00ICGROUP,INC.MELBOURNEJune5UNITEDSTATESDOLLARAUD50.07includesconversioncommissionofAUD1.469.96WOOLWORTHS3335CHADSTOCHADSTONE
```

I am looking to extract this from the above:

```
(ICGROUP,INC.MELBOURNE)June5UNITEDSTATESDOLLARAUD(50.07)includesconversioncommissionof
```

with the brackets representing the two groups I am after. The consistent parts across all instances of what I'm trying to extract is:

```
DIGITS (TEXT) DATE TEXT AMOUNT includesconversioncommissionof
```

I have been able to use the regex:

```
([A-Z][a-z]\d)[A-Z]AUD(\d\,?\d+?.\d*)includesconversioncommissionofAUD
```

to get me the date and the amount. I am struggling to find a way to get as per the example above the words `ICGROUP,INC.MELBOURNE`
I have tried putting `\d\d(.*)` before the above regex but that doesn't work for some reason.

Would appreciate if anyone is able to help with what I'm after!

Comment: What is this horrible format? In the part `WELLJune350.07`, how can you know where the date ends and where the amount starts? Okay, there is no June 35th, but what if it were `June250.07`? Is that 50 dollars on june 2, or 0.07 dollars on june 25?

Comment: That's quite tough and definitely stretching the bounds of what can be done sanely. Are you sure they can't send you the data with some delimiters? Is the value in the position after `ICGROUP,INC.MELBOURNE` always the full name of the month followed by a numeric day?

Comment: Hey! I've actually been to "LEO'SFINEFOOD&WINEHARTWELL" many times :)

Comment: And you paid them June350.0735.00ICGROUP,INC.MELBOURNEJune5UNITEDSTATESDOLLAR?

Comment: @mwp no, that was my evil twin brother. (I feel an impending "too chatty" flag)

Answer (score 1):

The closest I think we can get (PCRE) is something like:

```
/
  [\d,.]+                        # a currency value to bookend 
  (.+?)                          # capture everything in-between
  [A-Z][a-z]+\d+                 # a month followed by a day, e.g. "June5"
  .+?                            # everything in-between
  ([\d,.]+)                      # capture a currency value
  includesconversioncommissionof # our magic token to bookend
/x
```

The technique here is to pit greedy expressions against non-greedy expressions in a very deliberate way. Let me know if you have any questions about it. I would be extremely hesitant to put this in production—or even trust its output as an ad-hoc pass—without rigorous testing!

I'm using the pattern `[\d,.]` for currency, but you can replace that with something more sophisticated, especially if you expect weird formats and currency symbols. The biggest potential pitfall here is if the `ICGROUP,INC.MELBOURNE` token might start with a number. Then you'll definitely need a more sophisticated currency pattern!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've got (in php).

```
$string = "LEO'SFINEFOOD&WINEHARTWELLJune350.0735.00ICGROUP,INC.MELBOURNEJune5UNITEDSTATESDOLLARAUD50.07includesconversioncommissionofAUD1.469.96WOOLWORTHS3335CHADSTOCHADSTONE";

$cleaned = preg_replace("/^(LEO'SFINEFOOD&WINEHARTWELL)([A-Za-z]{3,9})(\.|\d)*/", "", $string);
echo $cleaned;
```

what it returns is: ICGROUP,INC.MELBOURNEJune5UNITEDSTATESDOLLARAUD50.07includesconversioncommissionofAUD1.469.96WOOLWORTHS3335CHADSTOCHADSTONE

Which you can then use and run your own little regex on.

Explanation:

The `\w{3,9}` is used to remove the month which may be 3-9 characters long. Then the `(\.|\d)*` is to remove the digits and dots. I'm thinking that we could parse the month/date better using your regex to extract that June 5 part but from your example given, it shouldn't be necessary.

However, it would be much more helpful if you could provide at least 3 examples, optimally 5, so we can get a good feel of the pattern. Otherwise this is the best I can do with what you've given.

Comment: @a-lau When you define a character class in a regex with `[]`, it by definition matches any character in that class. The pipe operator in your character class is therefore not necessary; in fact, it's wrong, because it will match a pipe character in the input string! You also don't need to escape the period character within a character class; PCRE understands from the context that you mean a literal period.

Comment: @mwp my mistake, was meant to be a round bracket. Will change.

Comment: Thanks for that. Managed to get it working thanks to all the responses!